# Android app, connect with an unknown bluetooth device

Tags: java, android, macos, networking, bluetooth

I am currently (for testing) using

```
private static String address = "07:12:05:16:66:69";
```

to connect to my own Bluetooth device, but can't figure out how to enable my app to get the MAC address of a device so that it can connect to others. I have attached my working MainActivity.

http://pastebin.com/KJPvJXG1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through device discovery process to see what device addresses are around you.  See the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices